# Removing arbitrary spacing in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

My word document is driving me round the bend.

There is a paragraph which is supposed to sit just before two excel-formatted graphs.

However the last sentence of so decides it wants to move to below the graphs, despite their being ample space on the previous page.

The attached picture illustrates the problem more than my terrible explanation:

[image]

I've tried everything I can think of, any suggestions?

Comment: [Keep lines and paragraphs together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-lines-and-paragraphs-together-d72af534-926f-4c4b-830a-abfc2daa3bfa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. "keep lines together" simply moves the whole paragraph over to the right hand side. Link this: [link](http://imgur.com/GTPI6sp) , I've also tried every combination of those check-boxes in the screenshot.

Comment: Did you try keeping the lines together, but **not** the paragraphs together?

Comment: Presumably you mean breaking them up as paragraphs but removing the spacing thus creating an artificial paragraph? I tried but no luck, see screenshot: [link](http://imgur.com/3tRepk0)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your picture is bigger than the empty space it is trying to fit. Right click on the image and change the "wrap text" option to something other than "inline with text" and your text should float up. The "Top and Bottom" option should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but they're already both set to top and bottom. I've tried every other format.

Comment: If you remove the image does the text slide back?

Comment: Yes, so I've resolved to just putting the images in the appendix instead. Hardly ideal but what can you do.